# Spyder Python 3.7 Why some methods are not shown after the dot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, spyder

If you press `Ctrl + Space bar` after an object name and a period (e.g. `objectname.`) you can see a pop up with associated methods to that object. For example, define `test2` as:

```
test2 = str('abracadabra')
```

If I type `test2.` and press `Ctrl + Space bar` I can see the main methods associated with this type of object (string)  such as `upper`, `format`, `split`, `replace`. However, not all methods are shown. For instance, `capitalize` is not shown, but it exists, as `test2.capitalize()` works.

Why `upper` is shown but not `capitalize`? Is this set by Spyder IDE? Wouldn't it be better to show all methods as you type them?